# Postgres: How to count records with ranged condition?

Tags: postgresql

Working with table with columns:

- (PK)sales_log_id
- user_id
- created_at

With sales_log_id to represent transaction activities for users.

I have been able to query how many users have x amount of transactions.

Now I would like to find out how many users have eg. > 10 AND < 20 transactions in a certain period of time.

Being new with databases and Postgres, I'm learning that you can do a query and another query with the previous result (subquery). So I tried to query first how many users are having < 30 transactions in June and later query the result for users having > 10 transactions.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.user_id) usercounter
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, created_at, sales_log_id
    FROM sales_log 
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN 
    '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' 
    GROUP BY user_id, created_at, sales_log_id 
    HAVING COUNT (sales_log_id) <30
)t
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING COUNT (t.sales_log.id) >10;
```

But it produced an error

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sales_log"
LINE 11: HAVING COUNT (t.sales_log.id) >10;
                       ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 359
```

Can anyone please provide the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is as simple as

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, COUNT(*)
   FROM sales_log
   WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30'
   GROUP BY user_id
   HAVING COUNT (sales_log_id) BETWEEN 11 AND 29
) AS q;
```

Only add `DISTINCT` to a query if you really need it.
It is just one word, but it can have a big performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I could do that.